# Display data repeatedly

Tags: javascript, php, html, frontend

I'm working on a website where I'm showing data from my MySQL database.
The data in the database is added every minute and I want to print that value **live** on my website. 
I'm using the following PHP code for a random number:

```
$randomNumber = rand(0, 1000);
```

How can i get this number to keep refreshing every minute without refreshing my browser?

Comment: Javascript probably has a random number generator, how is the random number related to PHP? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript **`setInterval()`** method.

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

Read more about it in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkntmhgt/) for an example for `setInterval()`.

The above fiddle uses a script as follows

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

which displays an alert every 3 seconds.

Instead of showing an alert, you can include your logic to calculate the random number, in the above example code.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS `setInterval()` to trigger Ajax function which will fire PHP function every X seconds.

Simple example with jQuery and PHP:

index.html

```
setInterval(function(){ $.ajax({ url: 'process.php',
         data: {refresh: 'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
             alert(output);
         }
});
}, 3000);
```

process.php:

```
if( isset($_POST['refresh'])) {
    $randomNumber = rand(0, 1000);
    echo $randomNumber;
}
```